# change tab displays all images and after min it shows original images

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using javascript easyslider for images

And the issue is I have four tabs, when i click on next tab it shows me image of next tab also, at the time of loading.

Please suggest any way ???

here are script :---

$(document).ready(function() {

```
  $('#reviews').imagesLoaded(function() {
          $("#slider1").easySlider({
                nextId: "slidernext1",
                prevId: "sliderprev1",
                speed: 150
            });
            if ($(".reviewsImage").find('li').length <= 1)
                {
                    $("#slidernext1").hide();
                    $("#sliderprev1").hide();
                }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please post your HTML and JavaScript so we can see what you've already got? That may also help to clarify your question for people.

Comment: Hey Douglas I edited the comment and add a script.

Comment: sorry, but I don't get it. Could you clearify your question?